# enable Access-Control-Allow-Headers in codeigniter (issue related to ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem when i try to make an ajax request to a controler's function. (`Codeigniter`)

Each time i make a request i get this error message:

```
Blocking a multi-origin request (Cross-Origin Request): the "Same Origin"
policy does not refer to the remote resource on http: //localhost/test.php. 
Reason: CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
```

I tried to add this in the top of php script (controler):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
```

But this not solved the problem ... when i use it in an external php script (Not codeigniter script) this work well.

Did you have an idea about how to solve this issue ?

Or another approch to send ajax request ?

*This question related to codeigniter, not same with pure php code.*

Comment: approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966) should do what you need

Comment: I want to solve the problem ?! i get the error message each time a make ajax call ! and in codeigniter not same as pure php ...

Comment: sure it is. Codeigniter is written in php. I have personally used that set up in codeigniter also

Comment: I just used it and don't work ! i learned that there an ouput library but i don't know how to use it and call it for use. this method do not work since i notified it in the post !